# Jquery DataTable to fetch data from an excel sheet

Tags: datatables

Can I fetch data from an excel sheet and present it in a webpage using DataTable (Jquery)

If yes then please suggest ways .
else ,suggest alternatives 
I am a beginner in using DataTable hence my question may sound weird.Apologies for it.

Comment: Are you wanting to make a web application or a static standalone webpage? (e.g. something you would save inside a zipped folder with resources to be sent out to people and used without a webserver)

Comment: I need to make a webbased app.Something kind of a dasboard that will fetch data uploaded in excel sheets by users and I need to reflect then on website ,with sorting functionalities.

Comment: What language would you like to use?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you need to open the Excel file on the server and convert it to Json.

Here's a Datatable example with AJAX and Json: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

That example loads the data from a database using, instead you'll have to use a library to open the Excel file, but which one depends on your implementation.